# Finding out Docker Container Running

Tags: linux, docker

I have a Linux machine at the company I work, and we know some web services are running on port 8111. I need to find out what is running check why the code is failing.

I do a `netstat -at` and I can see someone listening on the port:

```
tcp6       0      0 [::]:8111               [::]:*                  LISTEN
```

then I do a `sudo lsof -i:8111` and I get the proc that is doing the listening:

```
dockerd 64285 root  266u  IPv6 197189396      0t0  TCP *:8111 (LISTEN)
```

It's the docker daemon, so I do a `docker ps -a` but I don't see in the list a container that is listening on that port.

The person who was responsible for this abandoned the company and left no documentation, and just quit from one day to the next, and we are unable to get in touch with him.

Comment: The output of the console is not really helpful because ["dockerd is used for starting the Docker daemon"](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man8/dockerd.8.html). So we don't know which program do you use with docker.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Update**:
To get all Ids, Image names with Ports from running instances try:

`docker ps | tail -n +1 | awk '{print $1}' | xargs -n1 docker inspect | grep -E '"Id"|"Image"|"Ports"'`

Comment: That is the issue i dont know the container i want to find out the one